# jenkins build with bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I Have been working on bitbucket and jenkins for android applications. I am having many branches in my repository and i want to track just my master branch in jenkins where it meets the following criteria. 1) When we push any code with name 'A' into master it should automatically trigger a build.2) when we push a code as name 'B' into the same master branch it shouldn't trigger the build. Is there a way to do it. I tried excluding branch by using :^(?!.*release*).*$ but it is picking all other branches too. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which branch to be built in your job like this:

[image]

If you don't want the build to occur for specific codes then you can add them in to the `Excluded Regions`

Go to `Additional Behaviors` under `Git` in your job configuration and select `Polling ignores commits in certain paths`and add the paths to the files for those you want to ignore builds if any changes happen to them:

[image]

[image]

This should work!

Comment: Hey anil, Is there a way where we can trigger a build by making jenkins read the version code number in my build.gradle, like lets say my version code is 1 right now. and i want jenkins to read the build.gradle file in my app and trigger a build whenever the version code number is 1 and stop  building automatically when my version code number changes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little more?